# CRUD using LoaderManager and CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

I have a `MyListFragment` implementation which uses `MyCursorAdapter`. As the names suggest, they both extend the respective Android classes.

I read through [this Loader/LoaderManager tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html). So, now my query happens in

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) { 
        return new CursorLoader(blah1, blah2, blah3, blah4, blah5, blah6);
}
```

and the **LoaderManager** along with the **Loader** takes care of when to re-query and update, runs separate threads for queries, synchronize without having me to worry about it. So far so good.

I have 2 questions:

**1)** I have implemented a `MyContentProvider`. Where does this come into picture?
**->** It seems that the above `new CursorLoader(......)` makes the query through the `MyContentProvider` since it uses the URI as the first argument.

**2)** I also need to **delete / update / insert** items in the list. Should I just call my the respective methods from `MyContentProvider` inside `MyListFragment` at the desired places? If yes, then can I also load the items manually, without having the loader handle it? If not, then what is the **right way** to do it? I did not find any information online. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, thats correct it will call the query method in `MyContentProvider` with the arguments used in the `CursorLoader` constructor.
2. If I understood that correctly the answer is yes you can just call the `MyContentProvider` methods as long as they are calling `ContentResolver.notifyChange()` as it will cause the `CursorLoader` to get a new cursor (this is the whole point of using `CursorLoader`). When using `CursorLoader` you should avoid manually changing the data at all if you can so as to allow what is shown to always reflect the current set of data coming from `MyContentProvider`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the answer! That makes sense. I was not using `ContentResolver.notifyChange()`, so was wondering what was the point of putting the loader between. But now I see, all is connected!

Comment: But what if in my current CursorLoader, I also update some data belonging to a sibling fragment. That is not getting updated. Looks like I am still missing something.

Comment: As long as `notifyChange` is being called for the URI that fragment is using it should be updated.

Comment: I see. The sibling fragment uses a different Cursor Loader, though the notifyChange() is getting called on it through content resolver. I am just popping the current fragment to go back to this sibling. Should I be doing something in addition here?

Comment: No, but there are still other things to check for such as, do both the `CursorLoaders` have unique IDs? Are you managing fragment lifecycle events correctly?, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. If instead of popping, I use `FragmentTransaction.replace(foo,frag).commit()`, then it works fine. Not sure if this is the right way.